# Let $S :W →V$ and $T :V →W$ be linear transformations if $T ◦ S ◦ T = T$ and $S ◦ T ◦ S = S$ , then $T=S^{-1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $S :W →V$ and $T :V →W$ be linear transformations if $T ◦ S ◦ T = T$ and $S ◦ T ◦ S = S$ , then $T=S^{-1}$?

I've had an exam. In one of the questions, it is given that $S :W → V$ and $T :V → W$ be linear transformations and $T ◦ S ◦ T = T$ and $S ◦ T ◦ S = S$, so I used this argument and claimed that since $T ◦ S ◦ T = T$ and $S ◦ T ◦ S = S$ then $T=S^{-1}$. I would like to know why this is not true.

Comment: The easiest way to show that this is not true is to use a counterexample. In particular, take $S,T:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ to be the identical maps $S(x,y) = T(x,y) = (x,0)$. Show that $S$ and $T$ satisfy the equations, but $T \neq S^{-1}$ (and in fact, $S$ has no inverse).

Comment: **If** we are given that $S$ is invertible, then we can indeed conclude that $T = S^{-1}$.

Comment: See [Moore–Penrose pseudo-inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) for further examples.

Comment: we were asked to prove that V = Im S ⊕ ker T , in this case also it is not True ??

Answer (score 1):

With questions like these it's good to have some examples on hand. Trying the claim against various examples will hopefully either uncover a counterexample, or convince you that the claim is true.

One linear map you should *always* consider is the zero map, i.e. the map $Z: V \to W$ such that $Z(v) = 0$ for all $v \in V$. (Calling this map $Z$ is not standard, but I'll use this name in this answer.)

Now, let's consider the hypothesis of the claim using the zero map. It's easy to verify that $Z \circ Z \circ Z = Z$ (both sides are the zero map). So $T = S = Z$ satisfies the hypothesis of the claim. But the conclusion is obviously wrong. $Z$ is not an invertible map (it's as far from invertible as you can get!)

Comment: we were asked to prove that V = Im S ⊕ ker T , in this case also it is not True ??

Comment: That is true. Im $S = 0$ and $\ker T = V$ in my example.

Answer (score 0):

If $S$ is invertible, then the result obviously holds.

Otherwise, this is not true for any vector spaces $V$ and $W$. Take $S=T=0$.